# Magento, paypal: status pending

Tags: magento, paypal, status

Here goes my first question ever here @ stackoverflow. I've been working on setting up Paypal on a 1.7.0.2 Magento store. It worked using the PayPal express checkout with API settings (API username, API password and API signature).

Now, I've been able to get PayPal to show up on the checkoutpage. In fact; I've even made a couple of payments with another PayPal account! For a non-programmer hobyist like myself this is yet another milestone in setting up my sisters Magento store. However, one thing I can't figure out.

The PayPal transaction says it "pending", meaning that the seller has to clear the payment before any money is deducted. This is not desired behaviour. I want the money to be deducted from the buyers account immidiately.

Ofcourse, I've been googling and contacted PayPal (those guys don't even seem to know how PayPal works :s), without succes untill now. Hope you guys can help me out on this one.

Comment: I guess since Ebay took Paypal over it fired all its tech support. Guess the new guys dont know how the API works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the money to be deducted from the buyers account immidiately.

It's not really an answer, but check the "payment action" (in german it is "Zahlungsvorgang") at the "System->configuration->payment methods" tab. There's a difference between "Authorisation" and other ones.

There's a screenshot:

[image]

One of them only reserves the money, but it will not be transmitted ... you should have a look at this.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that one. Well, I did actually. In fact; I toggled it from the first option ("authorisierung") to the third ("Bestellung") and that didn't work. Completely overlooked the second option; "Verkauf" that get's the job done.

Thanks a whole bunch mate, that's about six hours of trying to figure this thing out solved in a single screenshot. Danke schön, I think it is :)

Comment: Great. I've also spend a lot of time to find out, that this tiny option can cause these annoying issues :)